# wget site from specific URL anad its subdirectories

Tags: html, wget

I am trying to download all HTML files to disk from https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/map/.  What I means is that I need to get the index.html and all the other HTML files after the https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/map/ URL ending with "map".  For instance, I need to download:

https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/**map**/income-support/extra-help/disability-allowance/medical-fees-01.html
https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/**map**/income-support/extra-help/community-costs/index.html

and so on.  I do not need to download any other HTML pages from the same site where **map** is not in the URL.  I have tried the wget command below:

```
wget --limit-rate=200k --recursive --html-extension --convert-links   --random-wait --follow-tags=a -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)" https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/map/index.html
```

With the above I get the https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/map/index.html and then the 
http://www.workandincome.govt.nz/robots.txt and then HTML files that I do not need like:

www.workandincome.govt.nz/online-services/index.html, www.workandincome.govt.nz/eligibility/index.html

Can someone please review the wget command I am using and advice?
Thanks

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Types-of-Files

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -A param

`wget -A "*map*" --limit-rate=200k --recursive --html-extension --convert-links   --random-wait --follow-tags=a -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)" https://www.workandincome.govt.nz/map/index.html`